# Combining Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, information-theory

If the following Markov chain relations hold:
$$X \rightarrow  Y  \rightarrow Z,$$
$$Z \rightarrow  W  \rightarrow Y,$$
can we combine them to have 
$$X \rightarrow  Y  \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W \rightarrow  Y?$$
If so,  what does $$Y  \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W \rightarrow  Y$$ say about $Y$?

I'd appreciate any references with similar problems.

Comment: I don't think your notation is standard. Please explain what your arrows mean. (My best guess is that $A \rightarrow B$ means "A can be reached from B with positive probability", but I am not sure).

Comment: This is the standard of information theory. $X \rightarrow  Y  \rightarrow Z,$ means p(x,z|y)=p(x|y)p(z|y), i.e., given $Y$, $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: Have you a specific situation in mind, where indeed $X \rightarrow  Y  \rightarrow Z$ and $Z \rightarrow  W  \rightarrow Y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, from $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ and $Z\rightarrow W \rightarrow U$ we cannot conclude $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z\rightarrow W\rightarrow U$. To have this last Markovity, we need to have $Y\rightarrow Z \rightarrow W$, too. That is, $p(w,y|z)=p(w|z)p(y|z)$ is also required too.

Regarding $ Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W \rightarrow Y$, when we write the definition of Markovity for $ Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow W$  and $ Z \rightarrow W \rightarrow Y$, we conclude that $ Y$ must be constant.

Comment: Why should $Y$ be constant if $Y-Z-W-Y$? Take $Y$ random, $Z$ a permutation of $Y$ and $W$ a permutation of $Z$.

Comment: Your statement regarding combining the Markov chains is incorrect. $X - Y  - Z$, $Y - Z - W$, and $Z - W - U$ do not imply $X - Y - Z - W - U$. As a counter example, consider $X$, $Z$, and $U$ related by xor with $Y$ and $W$ independent. Then $X - Y - Z$, $Y - Z - W$, and $Z - W - U$ are Markov chains, but $X - Z - U$ is not and so $X - Y - Z - W - U$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all $Y-Z-W-Y$ would imply that $Y$ is independent of itself given $Z$ or $W$, i.e., both $Z$ and $W$ are sufficient statistics for $Y$: $I(Y;Y|Z)=H(Y|Z)=0$.

But I do not think that this claim holds: The statements $X-Y-Z$ and $Y-W-Z$ neither imply $Y-Z-W$ (leading to your claim) nor $X-Y-W$ (leading to $X-Y-W-Z$).

Comment: @ Bernhard How can $Y$ be independent of itself?

Comment: Independent of itself, *conditioned on* Z and W (not or, actually). A deterministic Y would be independent of itself (or of anything, for that matter). In this case you only need Y to be conditionally deterministic. That is if p(Y|Z,W) is a delta.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot combine them like that, because there would actually be a loop in the dependency graph (the two Y's are the same node), and the resulting graph does not supply the necessary Markov relations X->Y->Z and Y->W->Z.

The proper conclusion to draw from the two Markov relations can only be:

X->Y->W->Z

because p(x,y,z) = \sum_w p(x,y,w,z) = p(x) p(y|x) \sum_w p(w|y) p(z|w), where the last term is a function of (y,z) only.

Comment: You can not conclude that $X - Y - W - Z$ form a Markov chain. Your derivation only shows that if $X - Y - W - Z$ form a Markov chain, then so do $X - Y - W$ and $Y - W - Z$. As a counter example, consider X, Y, and Z related by xor (that is, X and Y uniform independent binary variables, and $Z = X \oplus Y$) and W independent. Then $X - Y - W$ form a mc, $Y - W - Z$ form a mc, but $X - Y - W - Z$ do not because $X - Y - Z$ do not.