# How to combine two Markov Chains?

Tags: probability

Here is a problem I have been thinking about for a while but have not been able to find an answer.

- Suppose there are two groups of people : $\text{Group A:} \quad \text{and} \quad \text{Group B:}$
- There are 4 States (corresponding to a Discrete Time Markov Chain): $\text{State 1,} \quad \text{State 2,} \quad \text{State 3,} \quad \text{State 4}$
- A person within $\text{Group A}$ has the following probability of being in any one of these given states:

$$P_{\text{Group A}}(S_{t+1}=s_i|S_t=s_j) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & p_{14} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & p_{24} \\
p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33} & p_{34} \\
p_{41} & p_{42} & p_{43} & p_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

- A person within $\text{Group B}$ has the following probability of being in any one of these given states:

$$P_{\text{Group B}}(S_{t+1}=s_i|S_t=s_j) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p'_{11} & p'_{12} & p'_{13} & p'_{14} \\
p'_{21} & p'_{22} & p'_{23} & p'_{24} \\
p'_{31} & p'_{32} & p'_{33} & p'_{34} \\
p'_{41} & p'_{42} & p'_{43} & p'_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Note that $\sum_{j=1}^{4} p_{ij} = 1, \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and
  $\sum_{j=1}^{4} p'_{ij} = 1, \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$  and $p_{ij} \neq p'_{ij}, \quad \forall i, j$
- Now, suppose someone from Group A has the probability of going to Group B and a person from Group B has the probability of going to Group A (and of course, they can also both stay in their existing groups):

$$P_(Group_{t+1}=s_i|Group_{t}=s_j) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{AA} & p_{AB}  \\
p_{BA} & p_{BB} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**My Question:** Suppose at each time point, we first see if a person will stay in the same group or change groups - then, we see if this person will change states or not. If a person changes their group, they keep the same state they are currently in, but we apply the transition probabilities of the new group to see if they will change states.

E.g.

- @Time = 1 : Person is currently in Group A, State 1
- First, we check if Person will stay in Group A or change to Group B.
- Suppose this Person switched to Group B
- We now use Transition Matrix for Group B to see if this Person will switch States
- Suppose this Person has now gone to State 2
- At the end of Time = 1, Person is in Group B, State 2
- @Time = 2, Person is in Group B, State 2
- We check to see if Person will switch Groups or keep the same Group
- Then we use the corresponding transition matrix to see which State the Person will go to
- Now we are at the end of Time = 2
- Now, we start @Time = 3
- etc.

**Given this information, I am interested in answering questions such as: If a person is currently in Group A and in State 1**

- **After this person leaves State 1 for the first time, how many transitions (on average) will it take for this person to return to State 1 (does not matter if at the end in Group A or Group B)?**
- **How many transitions (on average) will it take for this person to return to Group A, State 1 after crossing into Group B at least once?**

Originally I was thinking of trying to combine the Group Matrix and the State Matrix into a single matrix, but I am not sure how to do this if the transition probabilities are different. Currently, I am planning on solving this question via simulation - but I was wondering if there is some mathematical formula (e.g. mean passage time, hitting time, absorption time) that can be used for these situations where are multiple Markov Chains involved?

Thanks!

References:

- [Combining Markov chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351974/combining-markov-chains)
- [Combined Markov Chain of N identical Markov Chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747871/combined-markov-chain-of-n-identical-markov-chains)

Answer (score 2):

You can build a single Markov process that represents all of the dynamics of your scenario.  The state of a person consists of which group they are in, and which of the 4 states they are in.

Therefore, this unified Markov process has 8 states (namely, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4).  You can write down explicit transition probabilities using the rules you've identified, and thereby obtain a 8x8 transition matrix for this unified Markov process.  Most of the entries in this matrix are zero, since when a person changes group, the rest of their state remains the same.

Then answering your questions about this Markov process amount to analysis of Markov processes, which is explained in standard sources.